# I want to show Diamond Shaped icon in my chart created using amCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amstock

I want to show diamond-shaped icon in my chart. I have created this charts using amCharts.

My present amChart:

[image]

And I want to put diamond-shaped icon just like in following image:

[image]

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function getChart(id) {
    var allCharts = AmCharts.charts;
    for (var i = 0; i < allCharts.length; i++) {
        if (id == allCharts[i].div.id) {
            return allCharts[i];
        }
    }
}


function load_holding_graph(graph_type, history, title, aggregate, industry){
        var title_1 = industry[0].ticker + '\n';
        var title_2 = industry[0].name;
        var title_3 = industry[0].industry + ' . ' + industry[0].sector;

        // current day exclude weekends
        var current_date = new Date();
        switch(current_date.getDay()){
            case 0: 
                  var s = new Date(current_date.getTime());
                  var d = s.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1); 
                  break;
            case 6: 
                  var s = new Date(current_date.getTime());
                  var d = s.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 2);
                  break;
            default:
                  var d = current_date;
        }
        var latest_trading_day = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM, yy', d);



    // CREATE DATA
    var chartData = [];
    generateChartData(history);

    function generateChartData() {

        for (var i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
            var date = new Date(history[i].date);

            var val = Math.round(Math.random() * (30) + 100);


            chartData[i] = ({
                date: date,
                open: history[i].open,
                close: history[i].close,
                high: history[i].high,
                low: history[i].low,
                volume: history[i].volume,
                value: val

            });
        }
    }

    // CHART CONFIG 
    var chartConfig = {
        type: "stock",
        pathToImages : "/static/img/amcharts/",
        addClassNames:true,



        dataSets: [{
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "open",
                toField: "open"
            }, {
                fromField: "close",
                toField: "close"
            }, {
                fromField: "high",
                toField: "high"
            }, {
                fromField: "low",
                toField: "low"
            }, {
                fromField: "volume",
                toField: "volume"
            }, {
                fromField: "val",
                toField: "val"
            }

            ],

            color: "#fff",
            dataProvider: chartData,
            title: title,
            categoryField: "date",
            compared: false,
        }, 
        {
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value"
            }],
            color: "#fff",
            dataProvider: chartData,
            title: title,
            categoryField: "date"
        },
        ],

        panels: [{

                addClassNames:true,
                percentHeight: 75,
                valueAxes: [{
                    id:"v1",
                    //logarithmic:true,
                    unit : '$',
                    unitPosition:"left",
                    position:"left",
                },
                {
                    id:"v2",
                    unit : '$',
                    unitPosition:"left",
                    position:"right",
                    synchronizeWith: "v1",
                    synchronizationMultiplier: 1,
                },

                ],


                marginBottom: 0,
                marginTop: 0,
                stockGraphs: [{type: graph_type,
                      id: "g1",
                      title:title,
                      openField: "open",
                      closeField: "close",
                      highField: "high",
                      lowField: "low",
                      valueField: "close",
                      lineColor: "#11EDF1",
                      fillColors: "#11EDF1",
                      negativeLineColor: "#db4c3c",
                      negativeFillColors: "#db4c3c",
                      fillAlphas: 1,
                      // comparedGraphLineThickness: 2,
                      columnWidth: 0.4,
                      useDataSetColors: false,
                      comparable: true,
                      compareField: "close",
                      bullet : "round",
                      bulletAlpha : 0,
                      showBalloon: true,
                      showBalloonAt:"top",
                      "balloonText":"$[[value]]",


                    } ],

                stockLegend: {
                    enabled:true,
                    useGraphSettings:true,
                    data:[{title: ""}],
                    // valueTextRegular: undefined,
                    periodValueTextComparing: "[[percents.value.close]]%",
                    markerType: "diamond",
                    backgroundColor :"#ffffff",
                    markerSize : 24,
                    position:"top",

                },

            },

        ],

        panelsSettings: {
          color: "#fff",
          plotAreaFillColors: "#333",
          plotAreaFillAlphas: 1,
          marginLeft: 60,
          marginRight: 60,
          marginTop: 20,
          marginBottom: 5,

        },

        categoryAxesSettings: {
          equalSpacing: true,
          gridColor: "#555",
          gridAlpha: 1,
          maxSeries:0,
          markPeriodChange:false,
          autoGridCount:true,
          minHorizontalGap:100,
          dateFormats: [{period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
                      {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
                      {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
                      {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
                      {period:'DD',format:'MMM DD, YYYY'},
                      {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
                      {period:'MM',format:'MMM YYYY'},
                      {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}],
        },

        valueAxesSettings: {
          gridColor: "#555",
          gridAlpha: 1,
          inside: false,
          showLastLabel: true,
        },

        chartCursorSettings: {
            pan: true,
            valueLineEnabled:true,
            valueLineBalloonEnabled:true,
            onePanelOnly:true,
        },

        legendSettings: {
          color: "#fff"
        },

        stockEventsSettings: {
          showAt: "high"
        },

        balloon: {
          textAlign: "left",
          offsetY: 10,
        }, 


        "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "backgroundColor": "#fff",
        },

    }

    AmCharts.charts = [];



    // CREATE CHART
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("holding-graph",chartConfig);
    console.log(chart)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your chart never uses data point grouping, either by having few data points or having it disabled, you should go with the `bulletField` solution @gerric proposed.

If the above does not apply, probably the best course of action is to use [Trend lines](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/TrendLine) for that.

A trend line is basically a line from one datetime/value pair to another. However, it can also have an icon attached at its either end, which we can exploit to add a diamond image (we're going to use SVG) at any point of the chart.

Here's an example of a ready-made chart:

```js
var icon = "M256,0L96,256l160,256l160-256L256,0z";

var chartData = [];
var iconDate, iconValue;

generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
    var val = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
    chartData.push({
      date: newDate,
      value1: val
    });
    if (i === 480) {
      iconDate = new Date(newDate);
      iconDate.setHours(12);
      iconValue = val;
    }
  }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "stock",
  "theme": "light",

  "dataSets": [{
    "fieldMappings": [{
      "fromField": "value1",
      "toField": "value1"
    }, {
      "fromField": "value2",
      "toField": "value2"
    }, {
      "fromField": "value3",
      "toField": "value3"
    }, {
      "fromField": "value4",
      "toField": "value4"
    }],
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "categoryField": "date"
  }],

  "panels": [{
    "stockGraphs": [{
      "id": "g1",
      "title": "Graph #1",
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "valueField": "value1",
      "useDataSetColors": false
    }],
    "trendLines": [{
      "initialValue": iconValue,
      "initialDate": iconDate,
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineColor": "#ff0000",
      "initialImage": {
        "svgPath": icon,
        "color": "#cc0000",
        "width": 15,
        "height": 25,
        "offsetX": -7
      },
      "finalValue": iconValue,
      "finalDate": iconDate
    }]
  }],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    "fullWidth": true,
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "bottom",
    "periods": [{
      "period": "MM",
      "selected": true,
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 month"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "count": 1,
      "label": "1 year"
    }, {
      "period": "YTD",
      "label": "YTD"
    }, {
      "period": "MAX",
      "label": "MAX"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: I have created an example in Jsfiddle  but getting some issue diamond not appears on the exact date location 
Here is Jsfiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/0bhxg8nh/1/

Comment: You might need to tweak the `offsetX` parameter. Here's your updated fiddle, that looks a bit better: http://jsfiddle.net/0bhxg8nh/2/

Comment: One more thing can i change the color of stock graph area ?? http://awesomescreenshot.com/02b57x1m19

Comment: Sure. Just need to set `backgroundAlpha: 1` and `backgroundColor: "#xxxxxx"` in your `panelsSettings`: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PanelsSettings#backgroundColor

Comment: I have tried this before when write these two properties color of graph outer boundary  changes here is the screen shot -> http://awesomescreenshot.com/04e57x5x40

Comment: can you please tell how i can dynamic offsetY parameter for showing diamond in graph http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cf57xkmec

Comment: Well you need to set the `initialValue` and `finalValue` to the value you want the diamond to be placed at. `offsetY` is only for finetuning the position. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89093/discussion-between-saf-and-martynasma).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`bulletField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmGraph#bulletField), you can set bullets from within your data. The diamond shape is already provided by `AmCharts`.
These two examples could help you out: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ow3uc1d/4/) & [amDemo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-with-custom-bullets/)

Comment: This is not 100% reliable, as the it would disappear when the chart would start grouping data points.

Comment: @martynasma then what would be the best solution and for now I'll use this

Comment: @gerric if i want to highlight particular diamond on specific date then how it is possible

Comment: You need to use StockEvent. I'll be able to post a separate answer later today, unless @gerric wants to update his answer. I'm fine either way.

Comment: @martynasma Yeah Please Post your answer one more thing i want highlight  one diamond on any specific date

Comment: @martynasma I'm fine with you posting an anwser. I never used `StockEvents` so I don't have any clue how they work. :)